# What set-theoretic definitions can't easily be formalized in a type theory?

Tags: mathematics, type-theory, set-theory

Most proof assistants (with some exceptions like [Isabelle/ZF](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/logics-ZF.pdf) or the [B method](https://www.atelierb.eu/en/presentation-of-the-b-method/b-and-its-different-languages/)) rely on **type theory**.

See also the MathOverflow question [What makes dependent type theory more suitable than set theory for proof assistants?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/376839/126609)

Next, formalizing mathematics is one of the main use cases of an interactive proof assistant.
But many pen-and-paper mathematical proofs are written in a **set-theoretic** fashion (e.g., in ZFC).

Finally, there are many different type theories (first-order, higher-order, dependently-typed or not, intuitionistic or not, etc.)

So, formalizing existing set-theoretic results *typically* involves some formal hindrances.

Keeping the constructiveness issue apart, and focusing on the definability of mathematical objects:

1. what mathematical concepts can't typically be "formalized as is", within the main proof-assistants / type-theories?
   (e.g., we can think about matrices in a non-dependently-typed theory…)
2. is a "workaround" possible, to still be able to formally deal with this mathematical concept in the considered theory? (if yes, feel free to cite a formalization example)

Comment: You might be interested in this: An initial algebra of a complete sup-lattice equipped with an endofunction is exactly a model of IZF... This can be formalized in type theories with HITs.

Comment: Thanks @Trebor (I guess we could say your answer refer to some "deep embedding"; while "shallow embedding"-like answers could be interesting as well)

Comment: I wasn't the close voter, but I presume the close vote was because this question seems to ask two questions instead of one, and most sites have a one-question-per-post policy.

Comment: Notably, even Isabelle/ZF shares with Isabelle/HOL a common root _Pure_ that is a very weak type theory.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Almost no pen-and-paper mathematics is written in ZFC. The vast majority of mathematical texts is actually written in something that resembles [structural set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) and is closer to type theory than to ZFC.

Most mathematics can be formulated in type theory in a fairly straightforward manner. However, not every brand of type theory is equally good for formalization of mathematics. Some type theories are more like programming languages, and others are geared towards formalization of mathematics.

Here are some features that make it easier to formalize mathematics in type theory:

1. *Quotients*: it is annoying to not be able to form quotients by equivalence relations. In type theories without quotients people use setoids (types equipped with equivalence relations) – and those who worked with setoids sometimes refer to the activity as "setoid hell".
2. *Impredicativity*: often a type theory does not have a type of truth values, but instead has a whole hierarchy of them (one in each universe). This leads to various complications because one has to keep track of universes.
3. *Extensional equality*: In type theory equality is represented by identity types. These may behave in unusual ways, unless we adopt some principles (such as Uniqueness of identity proofs or equality reflection).
4. *Function extensionality*: this principle states that $f, g : A \to B$ are equal if $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x : A$. It seems quite hard to do mathematics without this principle.
5. *Other extensionality principles:* these are principles like "equivalent propositions are equal" and "pairs are equal if their first and second components are equal".
6. *Excluded middle and the axiom of choice* are needed to a much lesser degree than one might expect.

Some type theories have all of the above constructions and principles, for instance the type theory of Lean. By doing so they sacrifice some good computational properties that "pure" type theories have (by this I mean that the type theory can be used a programming language as well as a foundation of mathematics). And there are alternatives which keep the good computational properties but require one to rethink how mathematics is done (such as cubical type theories).

Comment: small question: "to formalize type theory in mathematics" → did you mean "to formalize mathematics in type theory", maybe?

Comment: Why can't quotient types be added to type theory? Are there any consistency issues?

Comment: @M.Lonardi They can be added to a proof assistant. It might not be clear from the way it was written but lean has all of 1-6. HoTT also has quotient types, but without proof irrelevance I would argue that they don't act in the way one would normally expect, and I'm not sure if they are actually strong enough to escape "setoid hell".

Comment: @ErikMD: yes, thank you, fixed. I also tried to improve the phrasing that M.Leonardi alludes to.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: setoid hell arises because one has to verify that a map respects equivalences *all the time*, even when no quotients are really involved. The HoTT quotients are like any other quotients: you only need to check that something is being preserved when you map out of a quotient type. So I'd say it's not really setoid hell.

Comment: I am curious to know what do you mean when you say that HoTT can be used as a programming language. Are you referring to the translation into cubical type theory?

Comment: @Loïc:  Yes, I meant cubical type theory only. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that there are different kinds of impredicativity.  The propositional-resizing sort of impredicativity is indeed very helpful for formalizing mathematics (which sounds like what you were referring to), but impredicative quantification for a non-propositional universe is not really very relevant for mathematics.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro HoTT quotients do act the way you would expect when you talk only about types that are sets, because in that case you do have "local" proof-irrelevance.  It's best to think about HoTT not as saying that "the types you're used to act in weird ways" but rather that "in addition to the types you're familiar with that act in the usual way, there are also higher types that act in different ways".

Comment: @AndrejBauer: perhaps I have been too concise, I will try to be clearer. Quotient types were introduced by Giuseppe Peano in 1894 under the name "définition par abstraction"; second order logic + quotient types constitute an inconsistent theory; this is a form of Russell's paradox (Frege's basic law V is an example of a quotient type). And so, after reading that quotient types are sometimes replaced by setoids, I wondered: is it possible for this to happen in order to avoid Russell's paradox, in case the type theory in question is able to encode second-order logic?

Comment: Some bibliographic references: - for quotient types/abstractions [Notations de Logique Mathématique](https://books.google.it/books?id=OixPAAAAYAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&hl=it&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q&f=false) - for Frege's basic law V and Russell's paradox [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem)

Comment: @M.Lonardi: we should probably be a bit careful here with regards to specifying what formal systems we're working in. As understood nowadays, "second order logic + quotient types" does not constitute an inconsistent theory – so Peano must have done something different. But to answer your question: type theory with quotient types is of course possible and consistent (as consistent as anything else, say ZFC), and it can also encode higher-order logic.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I have given bibliographical references, I am sorry you have not looked at them. The proof is not by Peano, it is by Frege and it is in the appendix to the second volume of [Grundgesetze der Arithmetik](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_LZ5tAAAAMAAJ/page/252/mode/2up?view=theater); it is a famous appendix, it is the one where Frege says he received a letter from Russell.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't speak French, and I don't really have the time to read the extensive SEP entry and then guess which particular bit of it you're referring to. It is very likely I have seen the argument before, so if you'd be so kind to just outline it or point to a specific paragraph (written in English if possible) I will be more than happy to refresh my memory.

Comment: Paragraph number 2, about [Basic Law V](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege-theorem/#S2). Be careful: sometimes the proofs are hidden by a link, you have to click on it.

Comment: Thank you. So are you saying that Frege's development and the ensuing paradox applies to type theory with quotients? That is how I read your comments.

Comment: This is what I had asked you, I don't know the answer. The only thing I said was that second order logic + quotient types is inconsistent (because Frege's basic law V is an example of quotient types and second order logic + Frege's basic law V is inconsistent).

Comment: Ok. But that sort of argument doesn't carry over. Type theory with quotients is consistent, as it has set-theoretic models (as well as others).

Comment: Belated thanks for your answer @AndrejBauer !, and for mentioning [structural set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory).

Answer (score 11):

Andrej's answer that "Almost no pen-and-paper mathematics is written in ZFC" is correct.  But it's perhaps also worth noting that *some* pen-and-paper mathematics *is* written in ZFC (or, at least, something closer to ZFC than to type theory), such as much of the mathematics done by set theorists (in which phrase, of course, "set" refers traditionally to a ZFC-set).

A good deal of set theory *can* be rephrased more structurally to make sense in type theory, but this would be a rephrasing, and the amount of work that would be required is, I think, variable.  For instance, set theorists work with ordinals defined in the von Neumann way, with $\in$ as the well-founded relation.  This in particular implies that ordinals are literally *unique* representatives of isomorphism classes of well-ordered sets.  In type theory it is more natural to work "structurally" with arbitrary well-ordered sets rather than with von Neumann ordinals.  This makes some things more cumbersome because of isomorphisms that get carried around (although under univalence, these isomorphisms become equalities), but probably doesn't change things a whole lot.

On the other hand, as far as I know, no one has ever come up with a convincing structural presentation of Godel's constructible universe $L$.  The only structural approaches to $L$ that I know of essentially involve building a model of ZF(C) in some way and then constructing $L$ inside that model.  Note that $L$ is, as far as I know, still the only way to prove the relative consistency of the Axiom of Choice, so it is of interest even to mathematicians who don't care about ZF for its own sake.  (In contrast, the symmetric/permutation methods used to prove relative consistency of not-AC, and the forcing methods that can be used to prove consistency of other properties such as GCH and not-GCH, seem much more amenable to structuralization.)  *[Note: this paragraph was edited to remove a false claim that GCH is not forceable; see comments.]*

As another example, [Scott's trick](https://mathoverflow.net/a/306922/49) is a method used in pen-and-paper mathematics that is of interest beyond set theory, but relies on the axiom of foundation from ZFC, and so is not obviously formalizable in type theory.

Comment: You can force GCH using Easton (_class_) forcing. That’s essentially the same as good old forcing, but the poset used is a definable class instead of an element of the ground model.

Comment: Has there been a non-convincing strutural presenrtation of $L$?

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks, I didn't know that.  Can you point me to a reference?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think I was considering "building a model of ZFC and then constructing L in that model" as "non-convincing", i.e. "non-convincingly structural".

Comment: My intuitive and probably very wrong understanding of L in a type-theoretic setting is that it provides you with a `type_rect` operator that gives you access to the codes of the underlying universe as if they were implemented by induction-recursion, as in [Section 5.2 of this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01445835/document). Obviously it's not exactly the same thing but it's still pretty close in spirit.

Comment: @Pierre-MariePédrot Well, can you prove GCH and AC in a model like that?  That would be the first test for me of whether you have an L-like thing.

Comment: I had the same thought as PMP but I gave up on it because the construction of L is throwing in rather specific sets (the definable ones, in a suitable sense), whereas an inductive-recursive definition of `U` throws in functions `A → U`  from the *ambient* type theory. I am afraid this won't give enough control over what lands in `U`.

Comment: @MikeShulman You're welcome. The first reference I found is as Exercise 15.15 in [Jech's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-44761-X). A general consideration is that the preservation of Powerset and Replacement is not immediate with class-forcing. A second one, that generalizes for other cardinals, is that the standard forcing to add a new uncountable subset (without new initial segments) of $\omega_1$ will also make $\mathit{CH}$ true. There is also a [math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3814172/212120) on the resolution of that exercise.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks.  I would actually be interested already in a reference for how to force ordinary CH.  Why is this not better known?  Everyone always cites L as the reason why (G)CH is consistent but forcing as the reason why not-(G)CH is consistent.

Comment: @MikeShulman The main point is that L-like methods will never provide a model of ¬GCH. Quickly I'm finding Exercise IV.7.19 in [Kunen's](http://www.collegepublications.co.uk/logic/mlf/?00016) as a reference. The poset is the set of all partial functions from $\omega_1$ to $\{0,1\}$ with _at most countable_ domain (usual Cohen forcing uses finite domains). The sketched proof there uses a bit of machinery, but it actually follows elementarily that a surjection from $\omega_1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is in the extension. I'm not sure why this isn't “more famous”.

Comment: If you want to have **all** the details, you might want to peruse [our formalization](https://cs.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~pedro/forcing/Independence_CH/Definitions_Main.html) of that! Also Han & van Doorn also did this in Lean before, we are just finished.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks!  Can you also force AC?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible. Actually, you also can't force ¬AC: For obtaining that, you first extend through forcing and then pass to a submodel. The closest thing I seem to remember possible is to force Global Choice from a model with plain AC (but I do not recall if there are any other hypotheses missing).

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks!  I edited the post to clarify the situation.  So L is still the only known way to prove at least one important relative consistency result (AC), right?

Comment: Again, AFAIK, yes. It also seems to be essentially the only way to show that weakly inaccessible cardinals are equiconsistent with strongly inaccessible ones (which is surprising to me).

Comment: Two further comments:
(1) From weakly inaccessibles you can prove the existence of a transitive set model of ZFC, but the only way I know is essentially through $L$ (and I'm really shocked by this, considering how trivial is to do it from a strongly inaccessible).
(2) I just recalled that consistency of AC can be proved by using HOD (the inner model of hereditarily ordinal-definable sets). Nevertheless, this was also sketched originally by Gödel.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf And I doubt that HOD can be presented any more "structurally" than L, can it?

Comment: I don't think so, since it involves working the notion of first-order definability and ordinals (I'm not quite sure which is the culprit; at least the first one can be rephrased, as expounded in the old Kunen, by speaking of _definable sets_ instead, as a family closed under certain constructions).

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Most uses of ordinals can be easily rephrased structurally in terms of arbitrary well-founded relations.