# Can we automatically get around set-theoretic difficulties?

Tags: mathematics, set-theory, category-theory, consistency-strength

One of the main technical annoyances of working with (large) categories is the variety of set-theoretic difficulties that come about with it: if we use ZFC as background logic, then those large categories are not even objects of the universe of discourse (though individual large categories can be considered by formulas defining their objects), and even working around that, we can't perform constructions like that of functor categories between them.

The most common way to deal with them is to wave your hands and say "universes!" which magically makes all your worries go away. (This is of course a joke, but it is generally understood that any such worrisome issues can be easily dealt with by passing to a [higher universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe).) I imagine in the context of proof assistants this is fairly convenient, as they generally are based on type theory which commonly have a hierarchy of universes as a built-in feature.

However many "purists" would not be content with this resolution as Grothendieck universes have strictly higher consistency strength than ZFC. There has been a fair bit of discussion in the past about whether the use of universes is ever of any real necessity, with the consensus strongly leaning towards "no" (see for instance [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/382270/30186) or [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28913/30186), also [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35746/30186) specifically about Wiles' work). Very few of these arguments however do any kind of "formal analysis" which would unambiguously remove the necessity of universes from such arguments.

I hereby ask: have there been any proposals to provide some formal tools which could transform a proof using universes into a proof in ZFC? This of course cannot be done in complete generality because ZFC+universes is not conservative over ZFC, but I could imagine some tool of this sort for uses of universes in the style of category theory.

Comment: Note: [this question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/107/87) also asks about some aspects of transporting ideas between set theory and type theory, but rather different ones than the ones I ask about here.

Comment: A related question is: Are there any theorems which have been proven in a formal system that is not (known to be) conservative over ZFC, and where there is real doubt whether the proof works in ZFC? In other words, if someone produces such a formal tool, are there examples they can test it on?

Comment: See also https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/113/32

Comment: This sounds like a good task for Isabelle/ZF, though ymmv.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what the Liquid Tensor Experiment people eventually do about this.  They have formalised an argument due to Scholze and Clausen that does not raise set-theoretical issues, but I believe that they are also hoping to formalise the surrounding theory of Condensed/Pyknotic mathematics.  Barwick's pyknotic approach corresponds to just choosing a universe level, but the Scholze-Clausen approach avoids that and seems harder to formalise in Lean.

Comment: I tried to add the new (and perhaps relevant) [consistency-strength] tag. I was thinking a question involving this concept myself.

Comment: @AlexNelson Not at this point. I'm one of its (very?) few users, and the automation available there does not seem capable of handling that.

Comment: I think that this is the wrong question. I think that we're seeing now that ZFC is becoming inconvenient to use when it comes to some aspects of modern mathematics; section 4 of Scholze's "etale cohomology of diamonds" is an example of exactly what mathematicians should not be being forced to waste their time on. I think Grothendieck was right and it's time to move on. Logicians may like to worry about this sort of thing, however if you are actually worried about assuming that ZFC is consistent then one might ask why you're working in ZFC in the first place.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard I don't think worrying about the consistency of ZFC is the point of the question. Rather it seems to be asking about applications of proof assistants to [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics).

Comment: Reverse mathematics is not quite what I was thinking about when posing this question, but it is a nice way to put it in the broader context. I have no worries about consistency, but rather the question is whether the result is provable in some specific system of axioms (which many mathematicians agree on being a very natural one). There are many other questions in such reverse mathematics flavor one can ask, but in this question I do focus on one, which is the one which people most commonly raise.

Comment: @Wojowu Not really an answer, but I thought that it may be worth mentioning that I used ZFC in HOL to formalize some of the core theory about 1-categories. For example, see this [link](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/CZH_Universal_Constructions.html). I use the standard von Neumann hierarchy as a substitute for the Grothendieck universes. To get around the size-related difficulties, I modify the definition of a locally small category (I avoid the use of definability/reflection and other messy set-theoretic bits, but I never investigated the limits of my definitions).

Comment: Flow?: https://mathoverflow.net/a/373722/122794  https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00801 , but for: http://karagila.org/2020/flowing-to-conclusions/

Comment: @Rob Even if not for if its issues, how would Flow be relevant to the question?

Comment: Wojowu, you can implement ZFC and universes in Flow conservatively.

Comment: Interestingly, [the Wikipedia page on "Tarski-Grothendieck Set Theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory) mentions Mizar's and Metamath's implementation of Tarski's axiom.

Comment: I think this is a more subtle question than it appears at first glance. On MathOverflow, you can find a fairly detailed discussion of [Higher Topos Theory as a case study](https://mathoverflow.net/q/382270) for eliminating "unnecessarily strong axioms." My takeaway is that *if it really matters to you to stay inside ZFC*, then you should think through what you're doing, instead of hoping that a proof assistant can find a solution without your having to think. Conversely, if it *doesn't* really matter to you, then just go ahead and assume a slightly stronger axiom and don't fret about it.

Comment: A further comment: What is often needed to rewrite a proof in ZFC is not just some kind of *local* change, where you just use a slightly cleverer argument to prove the lemma of current interest, but a *global* change. You survey the entirety of your project, realize you never need more than such-and-such a level of generality, and formulate your definitions accordingly. This kind of global reformulation is not deep, but it's not easy to automate. The assistant can't know what global level of generality you need. Even if it did, do you really want to rewrite all your definitions and libraries?